# Service Fabric Actor backup works on 1 actor and fail on all the others

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have a SF application with 5 actors deployed in one common project. I need to backup the state of these actors.

Right now I am on a single node dev cluster. 
I followed the doc instructions and 1 actor works perfectly, backup and restore. When I try to do the same for other actors the backup fail. The Actor service for the failing actors are not attached to my extended actor service but to the base one, so I get "interface not implemented" exception when I try to call my backup logic.

If I step debug into one the actor methods and watch the ActorService property I get the confirm that it is not attached to my extended class, it is using the base one:

Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorService

the actor that works instead has ActorService of type of my extended class:

ExtActorService.MyActorService

I do exactly the same things for all the actors, why some are not registered with my custom class?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself.
The code was right, it was Visual studio that didn't publish correctly the updated packages to the cluster. Even if I got no build errors for some reason VS was publishing the same old packages to the cluster. I deleted the whole project on the cluster manager and rebuilt it in VS then deployed again, at that point all the actors behave correctly and do the backup and restore. Problem solved.